# Pandas conditional ranking

Tags: python, pandas, rank

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

[image: dataframe]

I would like to use the `pd.DataFrame.rank(axis=1, ascending=False)` feature to rank the dataframe subject to the condition that the value is greater than zero. That is, only values greater than zero should be ranked. All other values less than or equal to zero should be zero.

Can anyone offer some advice?

Thank you!

Comment: So, what must be the desired output for the sample?

Comment: Dont use png, use raw data and highlight as code

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df[df > 0].rank(axis=1, ascending=False)
```